# Login(over https) via some pop-up, while browsing site & being on same page(over http)

Tags: html, security, ssl, https

I need to allow users to login to a webapp, while they are browsing the site. So actually they can browse site with less privileges, for full privileges they must login. So I need to allow them to login while keeping them on the same page, preferably through a dialog box/ overlay or a popup kind of thing that would just let them login while being on same page  using username/password credentials.

Now the problem is that, I want to serve the entire site over http & just login/signup over https, so how could I switch from http on the normal page(that user is currently browsing) to https when the login dialog box shows up on the same page? Preferably I want to allow login while being on same page. How do I implement this behaviour ?

Answer (score 2):

From what you describe, I presume you're after a pop-up that hides the location bar, whether it is a different window (old-style pop-up) or a element on the page (AJAX-style pop-up).

The main problem such pop-ups is that they tend to prevent the user from checking the URL. The users won't be able to check that `https://` is used, that it is used with the site they expect and that no certificate verification errors have happened.

Unfortunately, only the users are in a position to check this, and not checking this would make the connection vulnerable to MITM attacks (e.g. for phishing).

If you want security, the users need to be able to check where they're logging into (not just your main site, but the page where they type their passwords).

(This identity verification issue is also linked to the second part of your question: you can't really use a self-signed certificate because your users wouldn't really know how to trust it.)

Comment: I was after an ajax style(element on page) popup for login. But I think it wont be possible to use https for login then, when I'm browsing the site over http & this too wont be secure, no!? So should I focus on creating a new window pop up like oauth dialogs of google,facebook!? Isn't there a secured way to do login using ajax stlye popup ?

Comment: @user01, as I said, no, there isn't a secure way to do ajax-style logins if the rest of the site isn't over HTTPS too.

Comment: so do I always have a paid solution to implement SSL, isn't there any way to do it free or at lower costs than those highly unreasonable prices of Verisign?

Answer (score 0):

> Now the problem is that, I want to serve the entire site over http

Don't bother with HTTPS authentication then.  If you want the site to be secure, you need to serve up every page over HTTPS, otherwise you're sending things like session identifiers in the clear.  What you're trying to do is like building a strong door when the wall is made of tissue paper, it's pointless.

Comment: but I saw most of the site do that, for e.g. linkedin login is over https & others over http. I also have a similar kind of application.

Comment: @user01 And that is totally insecure.  Take a look at the Firesheep attack.  Sites are consistently moving towards pure HTTPS because it's becoming increasingly clear that HTTP is wide open to any number of attacks.

Comment: This is kind of a ridiculous answer. Why wouldn't you want to secure the user's password, even if the site content was publicly exposed? Many people use the same password for multiple sites, and some of them may carry data with greater need for privacy.

Comment: @shannon because it's pointless.  Among many other attacks, if you access a HTTPS page from a HTTP page, there are ways for a man-in-the-middle to either strip TLS or spoof TLS and steal your password.  Trying to secure only a tiny portion of the site grants a false sense of security.  At best it's a waste of time, at worst it's actively harmful because it tricks people into thinking the site is secure.

Comment: Your claim that cleartext is no greater risk than a man-in-the-middle attack is false.

Comment: the goal I was referring to was not to secure a potion of the site, the goal I was referring to was to prevent transmission of the clear password. It's one thing to review a capture of data and collect passwords for everyone having visited your site. It's another to actively compromise all of the sessions in real time.

Comment: And by "false sense of security", you are referring to what exactly, when there is no indication given that the password is protected at all, since, per the question, HTTPS is not used? There is no UI indication that encryption is used.

Comment: @shannon I never made that claim.  I suggest you go read up on the SSL stripping attacks published by Moxie Marlinspike.

Comment: The SSL stripping attack reference is exactly the sort of real-time attack that I was referring to.

Answer (score 0):

To add to @Aurand's and @Bruno's excellent answers (+1'd), you could implement a system where anonymous users browse the site on HTTP, but before login takes place the current page is reloaded over HTTPS. Once reloaded an AJAX modal login dialog would be displayed.

So: `HTTP` -> User clicks `Login` -> `HTTPS` -> User can enter their `username` and `password` -> Submit -> Stays on `HTTPS`

If you go this route great care must be taken. The main things that spring to mind are:

- Use the [Secure Flag](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SecureFlag) for any authentication cookies that are set to ensure that they are only transmitted over HTTPS.
- Once a user logs in, they will remain on HTTPS for all site activity. You may return the user to HTTP after log out for anonymous browsing.
- Upon login or logout, you should renew any other session identifier tokens stored in cookies to prevent [Session Fixation](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_fixation).
- However, ideally all session identifying information should only be stored in the auth cookie with the secure flag set.
- You could maintain a simple cookie with the same expiry date/time as the authentication cookie, but this one would not have the secure flag set. e.g. `LoggedIn=true` and if this cookie is encountered on a HTTP connection then the user is redirected to the HTTPS version so they can continue their session (e.g. a returning user to the site where their authentication session was remembered or was still active). On the redirect to HTTPS their auth cookie is then verified and if unsuccessful the user would be returned to HTTP without the `LoggedIn=true` cookie so they can anonymously browse or login again.

However, it may be easier to redirect all users including anonymous ones to HTTPS all the time, remembering to include the Secure Flag on all cookies. The performance hit is minimal due to [Moore's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%27s_law).